# Getting an error in my Android App Widget

Tags: java, android, cordova, ionic-framework, android-widget

I've created an android widget almost a year ago. It works fine on devices with Android < 8.0, but mostly on Android 8.x.x, when the first time I install my app and place the widget on the homescreen, it shows an error with the message:

> PROBLEM LOADING WIDGET.

In the logcat there is no error.

NOTE: I'm using only those layout components that are allowed in Android Widget development, so this is not an issue. Also Force Stopping app, restarting device or sometimes removing and re-adding fix it for me.

I also tried removing most part of the UI and Code, but I'm not sure what is causing this.

This is a chunk of code, I also tried creating new widget from android studio, but it was also behaving the same way.

```
@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    for (int appWidgetId : appWidgetIds) {
        updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetId);
    }
}
```

[image]